# Annotating videos using VLC

Tags: annotations, vlc, bookmarks

When watching videos using VLC, I sometimes want to "bookmark" a 
specific point (or range) and add a text comment for later reference.

I realize I could have a word processor running and type in 
"filename.mov, second 2:17, note: blah blah blah", but is there an 
easier way? I'd like to do it w/ "right-click, menu item, type note" 
with the filename and time automatically noted.

If not, can I at least bookmark a specific location so that I can go 
back later to figure out what I found so fascinating about it?

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing to what you are speaking of would be the bookmarks function. Just go to playback, bookmarks, manage bookmarks. You can keep both windows up so it is more efficient.

Comment: OK, I did this, but when I closed VLC and restarted it, the bookmarks vanished. Is there some way to save them?

Comment: The feature was never finished completely so not you can't save bookmarks, however, it is open source so you coul.d easily add that feature in youself.

Comment: Is there a working feature that does what I want? I've edited open source before, but it's not my favorite thing in the world. Especially since I'm running VLC on Windows, and have no idea how to recompile there.

I know VLC lets you customize your menu, but am not sure if that helps me here.

Comment: @barrycarter the bookmarks are saved with playlist and not video.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the various VLAN addons like [Moments Tracker](https://addons.videolan.org/p/1426091/). Provided as a Lua script they can also be extended easily.